# How Do You Have A Nuget Package Copy Files Into A DotNet Core Project?

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget

I'm trying to create a Nuget package that will copy some files into the wwwroot folder of the application, but I can't seem to get it to work despite reading the documentation and looking at other questions online. Here is what I have so far.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>...</id>
    <version>...</version>
    <title>...</title>
    <authors>...</authors>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>...</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>...</description>
    <contentFiles>
      <files include="**/*.*" copyToOutput="true" buildAction="EmbeddedResource" />
    </contentFiles>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="ProjectName\bin\Release\**.dll" target="lib" />
    <file src="ProjectName\wwwroot\**.*" target="content\wwwroot" />
    <file src="ProjectName\wwwroot\**.*" target="contentFile\any\any\wwwroot" />
  </files>
</package>
```

It puts the files into the content and contentFile folders of the Nuget package as expected, but when referenced if does not copy the files into the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after checking the suggested link and the rest of the internet, here is the solution I came up with.

```
public static class ApplicationBuilderExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseMyApp(this IApplicationBuilder app) => UseMyApp(app, null);

    public static IApplicationBuilder UseMyApp(this IApplicationBuilder app, Action<Options> setupOptions)
    {
        var options = new Options();
        setupOptions?.Invoke(options);

        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            RequestPath = $"/{options.RoutePrefix}",
            FileProvider = new EmbeddedFileProvider(Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName("MyAssembly")), "MyAssembly.EmbeddedResourcesFolder")
        });

        return app;
    }

    public class Options
    {
        internal Options() { }

        public string RoutePrefix { get; set; } = "defaultRoutePrefix";
    }
}
```

Then, in your html you can reference the static files by doing something like this.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/routePrefix/fileName.extension" />`

It is not technically an answer to my question as stated, but it is clear now that what I was asking to do is not best practice - this is a much better way to do it.

Comment: I'm not sure where this "best practice" is coming from. Serving static files from a directory can be a far better solution in my opinion to embedded resources. Serving a static directory of files can be optimized in many many ways (nginx, cdn, web.config static file module, etc...) and never need to hit the asp.net pipeline. In a modular application, I would re-consider serving static assets as embedded files, as a primary strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Copying files into the project's source directory is not supported and has been a discouraged practice for classic projects.

However, the `contentFiles` section is meant to include files logically into the project so they can affect the built output. `buildAction="Content"` will add the files to the build and publish output. This allows to add content to a project without modifying its sources.

Comment: I get not wanting to have side affects on the referencing project, but then what is the proper way to package a project then if it includes DLLs and JavaScript and CSS that needs to be in the wwwroot folder?

I found a workaround that embeds the resources and then copies them where they need to go, but something less custom would be ideal.

Comment: Why does it need to go to `wwwroot`? there's no guarantee the hosting asp.net core application even has that folder or is configured to host static files. Swashbuckle for example embeds their UI related files and allows to configure a service into the application pipeline that serves them ([source](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI/Application/SwaggerUIBuilderExtensions.cs#L9))