# How to copy specific folder from a Razor Class Library to the destination via Nuget?

Tags: c#, nuget, visual-studio-2019, nuget-package, razor-class-library

I made a Razor class library project as following in .NET 5.0

[image]

I want to make a `NuGet` package with the `Areas` folder inside it

[image]

So that whenever this package is installed, the whole folder with all its files in the destination will be copied with the same name.

How to pack the whole `Areas` folder via `dotnet pack` command?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**1)** create a `<packages_id>.props` file under `build` folder of the project folder. In your side, it should be named as `RazorClassLibrary1.props` so that the file will work. See [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#include-msbuild-props-and-targets-in-a-package).

[image]

**And** if your nuget package is called `RazorClassLibrary1.1.0.0.nupkg`, the file should be `RazorClassLibrary1.props` and keep the name same as the package id.

**2)** add these under `RazorClassLibrary1.props`:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
   
        
    <Target Name="CopyFiles" BeforeTargets="Build">
        <ItemGroup>
            <File Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\Areas\**\*.*"></File>
        </ItemGroup>
        
        <Exec Command="xcopy /I/e/d/s/y %(File.Identity) $(ProjectDir)Areas\"></Exec>
            
    </Target>

</Project>
```

**3)** add these on `RazorClassLibrary1.csproj` file:

```
<ItemGroup>

        <None Include="Areas\**\*.*" Pack="true" PackagePath="Areas"></None>
        <None Include="build\RazorClassLibrary1.props" Pack="true" PackagePath="build"></None>

</ItemGroup>
```

**Also**, when you install this new version of nuget package, please [clean your nuget caches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) or delete all files under `C:\Users\xxx(current user)\.nuget\packages`.

**Besides**, here is [a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65285966/restore-nuget-package-in-different-folder).

Comment: Any clue how to make this copy .cshtml files too? For some reason it only copied the .cshtml.cs files for me.