# Copy files from the NuGet package to the destination project when installing the nuget package

Tags: nuget, content-management-system, episerver, optimizely

I'm working on the packaging part of module development and I was able to successfully create the package and install it on the destination site.

But I have an issue with copying files to the module folder in the destination project when installing. It creates some references for folders, not real folders. There are no physical files created in the modules folder in the destination project. But we noticed that it was created in the global NuGet folder on my computer (C:\Users<User>.nuget\packages).
Check the following Screenshots

[image: Solution View with reference]

[image: Physical files created in global NuGet folder]

I'm using Package.nuspec file and .targets file as follows:

**Package.nuspec**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
    <id>QBankModule6</id>
    <version>6.0.74</version>
    <title>QBank Module 6</title>
    <authors>QBNK AB</authors>
    <owners />
    <iconUrl>http://nuget.episerver.com/Framework/Styles/images/icons/default_package_icon.png</iconUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>QBank Module is a module for media support. The module includes a QBank tool for EPiServer.Cms.TinyMce 2.1.1.0 or higher versions and media references.  IMPORTANT: After first install, go to Admin mode to initiate QBank.</description>
    <tags>EPiServerModulePackage ThirdPartyAddOn Media Images DAM Mediabank Streaming QBank</tags>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework="net5.0">
        <dependency id="EPiServer.CMS.Core" version="[12.0.3, 13)" />
        <dependency id="RestSharp" version="106.11.7" />
        <dependency id="log4net" version="[2.0.0, 2.9999)" />
        <dependency id="HtmlAgilityPack" version="[1.8.4.0, 1.8.4.9)" />
      </group>
    </dependencies>
    <contentFiles>
      <files include="any/any/modules/_protected/QBankModule/ClientResources/Scripts/Editors/QBankMediaPicker.js" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true"/>
      <files include="any/any/modules/_protected/QBankModule/ClientResources/Scripts/qbank-connector.js" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true"/>
      <files include="any/any/modules/_protected/QBankModule/ClientResources/Scripts/QBankResponsiveLight-1.0.js" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true"/>
      <files include="any/any/modules/_protected/QBankModule/ClientResources/Scripts/jquery.js" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true"/>
      <files include="any/any/modules/_protected/QBankModule/ClientResources/Styles/qbankplugin.css" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true"/>
      <files include="any/any/modules/_protected/QBankModule/TinyPlugin/editor_plugin.js" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true"/>
      <files include="any/any/modules/_protected/QBankModule/module.config" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true"/>
      <files include="any/any/modules/_protected/QBankModule/lang/QbankModule_lang.xml" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true"/>
      <files include="any/any/modules/_protected/QBankModule/QBankModule.zip" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true"/>
      
      <files include="any/any/web.config.install.xdt" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true"/>
      <files include="any/any/web.config.uninstall.xdt" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true"/>
      
      <files include="any/any/QbankApi.dll" buildAction="Compile" copyToOutput="true"/>
      <files include="any/any/Qbank.Connector.Core.dll" buildAction="Compile" copyToOutput="true"/>
      <files include="any/any/Qbank.Connector.EpiCore.dll" buildAction="Compile" copyToOutput="true"/>
      <files include="any/any/Qbank.Connector.EpiCore11.dll" buildAction="Compile" copyToOutput="true"/>
      <files include="any/any/Qbank.Connector.EpiServerModule5.dll" buildAction="Compile" copyToOutput="true"/>
      
    </contentFiles>
                        
    
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="Qbank.Connector.EpiServerModule5/build/QBankModule6.targets" target="lib/net5.0" />
    <file src="Qbank.Connector.EpiServerModule5/bin/net5.0/QbankApi.dll" target="lib/net5.0" />
    <file src="Qbank.Connector.EpiServerModule5/bin/net5.0/Qbank.Connector.Core.dll" target="lib/net5.0" />
    <file src="Qbank.Connector.EpiServerModule5/bin/net5.0/Qbank.Connector.EpiCore.dll" target="lib/net5.0" />
    <file src="Qbank.Connector.EpiServerModule5/bin/net5.0/Qbank.Connector.EpiCore11.dll" target="lib/net5.0" />
    <file src="Qbank.Connector.EpiServerModule5/bin/net5.0/Qbank.Connector.EpiServerModule5.dll" target="lib/net5.0" />
    <!--<file src="Qbank.Connector.EpiServerModule5/ClientResources/Images/qbank-loader.gif" target="contentFiles/any/any/modules/_protected/QBankModule/ClientResources/Images/qbank-loader.gif" />-->
    <!--<file src="Qbank.Connector.EpiServerModule5/ClientResources/Images/qbankadd.png" target="contentFiles/any/any/modules/_protected/QBankModule/ClientResources/Images/qbankadd.png" />-->
    <file src="Qbank.Connector.EpiServerModule5/ClientResources/Scripts/Editors/QBankMediaPicker.js" target="contentFiles/any/any/modules/_protected/QBankModule/ClientResources/Scripts/Editors/QBankMediaPicker.js" />
    <file src="Qbank.Connector.EpiServerModule5/ClientResources/Scripts/qbank-connector.js" target="contentFiles/any/any/modules/_protected/QBankModule/ClientResources/Scripts/qbank-connector.js" />
    <file src="Qbank.Connector.EpiServerModule5/ClientResources/Scripts/QBankResponsiveLight-1.0.js" target="contentFiles/any/any/modules/_protected/QBankModule/ClientResources/Scripts/QBankResponsiveLight-1.0.js" />
    <file src="Qbank.Connector.EpiServerModule5/ClientResources/Scripts/jquery.js" target="contentFiles/any/any/modules/_protected/QBankModule/ClientResources/Scripts/jquery.js" />
    <file src="Qbank.Connector.EpiServerModule5/ClientResources/Styles/qbankplugin.css" target="contentFiles/any/any/modules/_protected/QBankModule/ClientResources/Styles/qbankplugin.css" />
    <file src="Qbank.Connector.EpiServerModule5/TinyPlugin/editor_plugin.js" target="contentFiles/any/any/modules/_protected/QBankModule/TinyPlugin/editor_plugin.js" />
    <!--<file src="Qbank.Connector.EpiServerModule5/TinyPlugin/Img/qbank.png" target="contentFiles/any/any/modules/_protected/QBankModule/TinyPlugin/Img/qbank.png" />-->
    <file src="Qbank.Connector.EpiServerModule5/module.config" target="contentFiles/any/any/modules/_protected/QBankModule/module.config" />
    <file src="Qbank.Connector.EpiServerModule5/Lang/QbankModule_lang.xml" target="contentFiles/any/any/modules/_protected/QBankModule/lang/QbankModule_lang.xml" />
    <file src="Qbank.Connector.EpiServerModule5/web.config.install.xdt" target="contentFiles/any/any"/>
    <file src="Qbank.Connector.EpiServerModule5/web.config.uninstall.xdt" target="contentFiles/any/any"/>
    <!--CDN Solution-->
    <!--<file src="Qbank.Connector.EpiServerModule5/ClientResources/Images/qbankaudio.png" target="contentFiles/any/any/modules/_protected/QBankModule/ClientResources/Images/qbankaudio.png" />-->
    <!--<file src="Qbank.Connector.EpiServerModule5/ClientResources/Images/qbankdocument.png" target="contentFiles/any/any/modules/_protected/QBankModule/ClientResources/Images/qbankdocument.png" />-->
    <!--<file src="Qbank.Connector.EpiServerModule5/ClientResources/Images/qbankvideo.png" target="contentFiles/any/any/modules/_protected/QBankModule/ClientResources/Images/qbankvideo.png" />-->
    <!--<file src="Qbank.Connector.EpiServerModule5/build/QBankModule6.props" target="build" />-->
    <file src="Qbank.Connector.EpiServerModule5/build/QBankModule6.targets" target="build" />
    <file src="Qbank.Connector.EpiServerModule5/QbankModule.zip" target="contentFiles/any/any/modules/_protected/QBankModule/QBankModule.zip" />

  </files>
</package>
```

**QBankModule6.targets**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0">

  <ItemGroup>
    <SourceScripts Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\..\contentFiles\any\any\modules\_protected\**\*.*"/>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="CopyZipFiles" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Copy
            SourceFiles="@(SourceScripts)"
            DestinationFolder="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\modules\_protected\%(RecursiveDir)"
        />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Also, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65218578/why-are-content-files-from-nuget-packages-added-as-links-in-net-core-projects-a) post an implemented solutions mentioned in the post. But ended up with the same result.

Basically, I need to understand how to copy some files from the NuGet package to the destination project when installing the nuget package. And also the difference between `<files>` tag and `<contentFiles>` tag in nuspec file.

Any input from someone who has experience on this would be great!

Comment: I have same problem. Can't find a solution..